# Plot 3D function with OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I need to build some sort of engine that can take a multivariable function such as

```
f(x,y) = cos(x) + y
```

and produce it's graph in 3D space.

Is there a recommended method of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is rather trivial. First you should start drawing a grid. Simplified, I'd just define a quad using four vertices. `x` would be `x`,  `y` would be `y`:

```
(0, 0, 0)
(0, 1, 0)
(1, 1, 0)
(1, 0, 0)
```

But how to get `z`? You simply assume `z = f(x, y)`, so you'd get something like this:

```
(0, 0, f(0, 0))
(0, 1, f(0, 1))
(1, 1, f(1, 1))
(1, 0, f(1, 0))
```

Then just use these vertices to actually draw something in your 3D space.